# Stack Overflow account locked out (error, not banned)

Tags: support, status-completed, merge-accounts

I've somehow locked myself out of my original and primary Stack Overflow account (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2365197/shishir-gupta) .

What happened was, I'd created that account using 'Facebook login'. Now, I wanted to attach my primary email account with the mentioned Stack Overflow account. After adding my email to the Stack Overflow account, and logging back, I realised I had another account on Stack Overflow (which I'd forgotten completely) associated with the email address.

Now, I can't go back to my original account (the one with link provided), as login through Facebook has created this account which I'm asking this question, and email login takes me to the old account about which I'd forgotten.

Comment: @Martijn Hmm? This looks like a completely different thing to me.

Comment: @Stijn: Indeed! I think the problem I linked to also created some other effects. See [Serious consistency error happening on main site now](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253642) for example. That or I got a tab mixed up. My comment is entirely misplaced here, removed.

Comment: @Stijn: ah, no. Tab confusion, [this was the post I was thinking of](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253641/submitting-error-copy-to-the-rescue).

Comment: Hm, you wound up with multiple accounts, then something went wrong with an attempt to merge them. Folks on the SE end are looking into this, just sit tight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Stack Overflow, as [a CM mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253640/stackoverflow-account-locked-out-error-not-banned#comment15628_253640), system was in the process of merging duplicate accounts, and now I've recovered back my account as well as both the accounts have been merged.